# Make the colour AND marker of bokeh plot scatter points dependent on dataframe values

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh

I've been playing around with bokeh in order to get an interactive scatter plot, with tooltips and interactive legends etc.

Currently I am able to set the colour of the points using the values of a column in the pandas dataframe behind the plot. However I'm wondering if it's possible to set the marker type (diamond, circle, square etc.) as well, using another column in the dataframe?

I appreciate this would mean you'd need a double legend, but hopefully this wouldn't be too much of a problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be accomplished with `marker_map` and CDS filters:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file
from bokeh.sampledata.iris import flowers
from bokeh.transform import factor_cmap, factor_mark

SPECIES = ['setosa', 'versicolor', 'virginica']
MARKERS = ['hex', 'circle_x', 'triangle']

p = figure(title = "Iris Morphology", background_fill_color="#fafafa")
p.xaxis.axis_label = 'Petal Length'
p.yaxis.axis_label = 'Sepal Width'

p.scatter("petal_length", "sepal_width", source=flowers, legend="species", 
          fill_alpha=0.4, size=12,
          marker=factor_mark('species', MARKERS, SPECIES),
          color=factor_cmap('species', 'Category10_3', SPECIES))

show(p)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help @bigreddot. In this solution, would it be possible to have points which are different combinations of colours and shapes? I.e. a point which is a square and blue, one which is a triangle and green and one that is a square and green.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. The above plot has points which are different combinations of colors and shapes. In any case, you can set the `color` value above to any color you like.

Comment: In your plot above, all the circles are red, all the squares are green and all the triangles are blue. Would it be possible to have a plot where both marker and shape are decided by the data, which would lead to some squares being green while other squares being red for example? My guess would be using the color argument of p.circle/square/triangle

Comment: Yes, the `color` argument can also be the name of a column in the data source, and you can fill that column with color values for each individual marker. Or, `color` can be a color mapper or `CustomJSTransform` that can colormap the markers dynamically in the browser, based on other columns. There are lots of examples in the docs.